# Wordpress, where to identify the permalink error?

Tags: html, wordpress, permalinks

I have a html code which links to the function.php to gets the URL for the a href.

```
<a href="<?php echo projectTheme_post_new_link(); ?>"><?php echo __("Post New",'ProjectTheme'); ?>
```

Originally it was working with this url: http://www.wastebidder.com/waste/post-new-project/?post_new_step=1&projectid=949

Now the link does not appear to go the that page and copying that URL DOES NOT WORK! it goes to the 404.php.

The HTML a href looks like this now:

```
 <a href>Post New</a>
```

The other permalink works perfectly fine, I just need to know how I am able to solve it.

Function part 1

```
 function projectTheme_post_new_link()
    {
        return get_permalink(get_option('ProjectTheme_post_new_page_id'));  
    }
```

I am Guessing the URL function:

```
 function ProjectTheme_post_new_with_pid_stuff_thg($pid, $step = 1, $fin = 'no')
    {
        $using_perm = ProjectTheme_using_permalinks();
           if($using_perm)  return get_permalink(get_option('ProjectTheme_post_new_page_id')). "?post_new_step=".$step."&".($fin != "no" ? 'finalize=1&' : '' )."projectid=" . $pid;
         else return get_bloginfo('siteurl'). "/?page_id=". get_option('ProjectTheme_post_new_page_id'). "&".($fin != "no" ? 'finalize=1&' : '' )."post_new_step=".$step."&projectid=" . $pid;  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the `projectTheme_post_new_link()` function's source code?

Comment: There is two functions - I wonder if it has anything to do with the database - PHPMYAdmin

Comment: It looks like only the first function is being used in creating your links, and if thats true then I would guess that the `ProjectTheme_post_new_page_id` option is not set, or set to something invalid (like 0).

Comment: ProjectTheme_post_new_page_id is coming from the database, and I deleted some data on a different database table which adds the user's input into the database

Comment: Browse to this url, replacing the `yoursite.com` with your actual website URL: `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/options.php`. Now, find `ProjectTheme_post_new_page_id` (using CTRL+F or just by scrolling) and check its value. It should be a non-zero number, specifically the page ID you plan on linking to.

Comment: Ahh Thank you, I just realised I deleted one of the id's which links to that page.

Comment: Woo hoo! If your problem is solved then be sure to answer your question with the final solution (and give it the checkmark). Glad to help.

Comment: Problem Solved: Missing ID from the database - just added the missing ID along with other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMYADMIN

Did not realise I have deleted one of the id's linking to ProjectTheme_post_new_page_id 
Just added the missing id, and filled the other information in, then it WORKED.

WOOHOO!!